# Can one thread directly make another thread wait?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, is it possible for one thread to cause another thread to wait by calling wait(), or without signaling of some kind?  I'm not actually trying to achieve or implement some practical end, like in the post [How to synchronize shared data between threads by using pause then resume or alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952636/how-to-immediately-pause-another-thread).  This is more of a theoretical exploration of whether such a thing possible in Java threading.

Comment: I think yes.... because main is a thread and it can make other threads wait...

Comment: No, it is not possible to pause other thread, unless you care to use deprecated and unsafe methods like suspend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to immediately pause another Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952636/how-to-immediately-pause-another-thread)

Comment: @OlegEstekhin: Or to put it less ideologically: it is still *possible*, but you probably [*shouldn't*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot safely and reliably pause a thread using normal Java. Threads can pause themselves but not each other.

Threads do have `suspend` and `resume` methods, but as it turned out, they're not safe and can easily cause your whole program to freeze (deadlock). You really don't want to have to use them.

Comment: Isn't it the case only when the threads are using some sort of resource locking? Assuming that my thread do not use any locking, can I use suspend and resume safely?

Comment: @KDM Lots of things use locking without you knowing. For example, `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible from one thread to make another thread to wait/pause by calling wait() method.

Locking mechanism (synchronization) is the safest way to make the other threads to wait till the execution of the thread which acquired the lock to complete.